# user store data out side problem i want to store data in side of new group in side of "Groups"i create a group now i storing data inside of new group

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

i created a group inside the child "Groups". inside of "Groups" i have one group. i want to store or add user in group, but my user data is displaying outside the group.

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contact model) {
    final String list_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

    UsersRef.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String userStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                holder.userName.setText(userName);
                holder.userStatus.setText(userStatus);

                Picasso.get().load(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);
            }

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String groupId = GroupRef.push().getKey();

                    GroupRef.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                            .setValue("Saved").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        GroupRef.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                                .setValue("Saved").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                            AddMemberRequest.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                                                    .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                AddMemberRequest.child(groupId).child("Members").child(list_user_id)
                                                                                        .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                            @Override
                                                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Member Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        });
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
```

i try to store data inside of

```
child("Groups").Child (... group id i want this id).child("Members").child("list user id").
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).